# Getting __str__ returned non-string error after adding a form on a page

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I have a search bar. After search an order code I want to open a new page with order information and a new form for items at the same page. Searching and getting order information works great. But after add a new form to the page I'm getting an error

```
TypeError at /paketle/
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Here is my models:

```html
class Siparisler(models.Model):

    siparis_no = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ..

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Sipariş"
        verbose_name_plural = "Siparişler"



    def __str__(self):
        return self.siparis_no

class Urunler(models.Model):

    urun_adi = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
    barkod = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ürün"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ürünler"
        ordering = ['pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.urun_adi

class Paket(models.Model):

    siparis = models.ForeignKey(Siparisler,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='siparis_paket')
    urun = models.ForeignKey(Urunler,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='urun_siparis_paket')
    miktar = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=True,null=True)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Paket"
        verbose_name_plural = "Paketler"
        ordering = ['-pk']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.siparis.siparis_no
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Paket


class PaketForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = Paket
      fields = '__all__'
```

my views here:
my views here:
my views

```html
class Paketleme(CreateView):

    model = Paket
    template_name = "siparis_paketle.html"
    form_class = PaketForm
    success_url = '/paketara/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            sorgu = self.request.POST.get('sorgu')
            query = get_object_or_404(Siparisler, pazar_yeri_kargo_kodu=sorgu)
            context['object'] = query
        return context




class Paketle(TemplateView):
    template_name = "paketleme.html"


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        bekleyensiparis = Siparisler.objects.filter(siparis_durum=1).count()
        bugun_siparis = Siparisler.objects.filter(siparis_tarih=datetime.today()).count()
        gunsayisi = 3
        geciken_siparis = Siparisler.objects.filter(siparis_tarih__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=gunsayisi)).count()
        iptaliadesipari = Siparisler.objects.filter(siparis_durum=9).count()
        context['iptaliadesipari'] = iptaliadesipari
        context['geciken_siparis'] = geciken_siparis
        context['bugunsiparis'] = bugun_siparis
        context['bekleyen'] = bekleyensiparis

        return context
```

I'm getting error after adding {{form}} on teplate page (siparis_paketle.html).

What is the problem here?

Comment: `urun_adi` has `null=True`, so it can be `None`, and then your `__str__` does return `None`, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

in the model Paket : self.siparis stores "Ids" of Siparisler. You can't use it this way:

```
 def __str__(self):
        return self.siparis.siparis_no
```

Just remove it